# Custom permission evaluator for spring security throws ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, proxy

> I've already found out what was wrong, just posting it here so googling  this exception would return something other than Hibernate problems.

I'm trying to set up Spring Security 4 with a custom permission evaluator, but getting this exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.web.FilterInvocation
```

then I'm requesting a `http://localhost:8080/my-service/secured/root@boss`, which is supposed to evaluate this method:

```
@Controller
public class SecuredServiceController {

@Autowired
private SecuredService securedService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/secured/{name:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#name, 'view.%')")
public ModelAndView stuff(@PathVariable("name") String name) throws ServletException, IOException {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("hello");

    model.addObject("message", securedService.getSecret(name));
    return model;
}}
```

but it's not getting called, the exception is thrown far before that.

Here is my `spring-security.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/free" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/test*" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-url="/logout"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
<bean id="myAuthenticationProvider"
      class="com.me.webcommon.spring_auth.MySpringAuthenticationProvider"/>

<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</security:global-method-security>

<bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="com.me.webcommon.spring_auth.MyPermissionEvaluator"/>

<context:component-scan
        base-package="com.me.webcommon.spring_auth"/>
<bean id="expressionHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking closely at the exception, it says that a method proxy can't be cast to a filter proxy. This is because I should be using a method expression handler 
`org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler`
instead if `org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler`
and spring creates a wrong kind of proxy object to retrieve arguments from the call and pass them to my `permissionEvaluator` before calling the method.

Here is a working `spring-security.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/free" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/test*" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-url="/logout"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
<bean id="myAuthenticationProvider"
      class="com.me.webcommon.spring_auth.MySpringAuthenticationProvider"/>

<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</security:global-method-security>

<bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="com.me.webcommon.spring_auth.MyPermissionEvaluator"/>

<context:component-scan
        base-package="com.me.webcommon.spring_auth"/>
<!--here, it must be a method expression handler-->
<bean id="expressionHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Wow... I wasted almost a full day on this exact problem. I was using a DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler and started getting getting the proxy / filter exception when I tried adding @PreAuthorize annotations. Changing to DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler solved the problem. The funny thing is I started of with a DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler but switched to a DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler to solve some other problem that I can't remember anymore. Many thanks for taking the time to post this for posterity.